# serialize() error when trying to fire an event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I've been trying to debug this error since yesterday with no luck..I'm trying to fire an event so that it's broadcasted via Pusher then handled with Echo, weird thing is that it worked for like 9 messages then it just stopped working, even when it worked the error was still being thrown, here's the error from artisan Tinker:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYIDX.png]

The event:

```
class ClientAdded extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $client;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('clients');
    }
}
```

Code from `BroadcastingManager.php` that's throwing the error:

```
$this->app->make('queue')->connection($connection)->pushOn(
    $queue, BroadcastEvent::class, ['event' => serialize(clone $event)]
);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by removing `extends Event`.